# How to use @RequestMapping having multiple Controllers for multiple Portlets in a Liferay Portlet Plugin

Tags: controller, annotations, request, liferay, spring-portlet-mvc

I have a WAR file containing two portlets with their dedicated controllers. 
How do I have to configure it that all controllers (handler methods) will be found when I start Liferay/invoke the page containing the two portlets?
In portlet.xml both portlets can be found both having 
`<portlet-class>org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet</portlet-class>`.

In spring-mvc-portlet.xml I use `<context:component-scan base-package="com.foo.bar" />`.

Both controllers shall have a default handler method annotated with @RenderMapping.
The controllers are both annotsated with @RequestMapping("VIEW") at type level.

What presently happens is that only the default handler method from controller A (the first one defined in portlet.xml) is invoked.

Comment: I solved the problem and this way works for me:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem solved!

I solved the problem and this way works for me:
I had to put each controller into its own package. To make Liferay aware of this I had to configure `portlet.xml`
in a way to give each portlet which is listed a dedicated context configuration. Thus, I copied the `<myPortlet>-portlet.xml`, 
renamed it properly to `<myOtherPortlet>-portlet.xml` and put this name into the 
`contextConfigParam <init-param>` element in portlet.xml.
Within the context config files I had to modify the context:component-scan element as follows to exclude the other controller to be 
disregarded for this controller. For example, in the context configuration XML file for my ListController I have to exclude the 
ImportController this way:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.foo.bar" use-default-filters="true">
    <context:exclude-filter type="assignable" expression="com.foo.bar.importer.portlet.ImportController"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

...and in the context configuration XML file for the ImportController I have to exclude the ListController accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

First I would suggest that you have each portlet (controllers) in separate packages.

For each portlet you should have spring xml file named after "portlet-name" from portlet.xml
So if you have `<portlet-name>my-first-portlet</portlet-name>` you shoud have **myfirstportlet-portlet.xml**, in WEB-INF, that has component-scan element.

Comment: Thank you, Martin. This is not enough and I think it is not required to name the files this way (nevertheless a good idea for naming). As long as I edit the contextConfigLocation element in the according portlet in portlet.xml properly the files can have a name as you wish.

Comment: spring will lookup automaticaly for files named as described in answer or you can use contextConfigLocation. Cheers

Comment: Ah! Okay. Interrsting. Thank you.